# Play flash video in slow motion

Tags: flash, actionscript

I'm working with flowplayer and accordingly ActionScript. This project has slowmotion plugin, but there are two imperfections: it uses the special stream server and no sound in slow motion. Is there possibility to play flash video and audio in slow motion by just add something in ActionScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I know, that is not possible. Slow motion and fast playback is possible if you use [Wowza Media Server](http://www.wowzamedia.com) in conjunction with a player made in ActionScript 3, but I don't think it's possible only using Actionscript.

You could try a combination of play and pause events, in rapid sequence, but the sound would be obviously interrupted. However, I've tried frame-by-frame playback with Flash and due to the codec structure, I think, the result was very inconsistent. Sometimes the 3 frames in a row would be the same, sometimes they would all be different.

Comment: In your frame-by-frame playback can you hear the audio?

Comment: I don't think you hear audio when you play back frame by frame. Also, I think you can only seek to keyframes. I could be wrong though. Might depend on the video format and the amount of meta data included in the video stream.

Comment: it is the main requirement for me to play audio with video